# Unity 3D : Converting variables declaration from JS to C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a pretty huge code to convert from JS to C# because of a joystick that I am using and I know barely C# so I was wondering if you could help me.

I already converted the functions to void.
I just need help for the declaration, for example:

In Javascript it's :

```
var SpawnPoint : Transform;
```

[Here is my source code](http://pastebin.com/1rV2mSAg)

Comment: Do you need help in some specific section or just asking someone to do the work?

Comment: No no I just need information about the variable declaration. I don't need you to convert the whole script for me lol it's 400 hundred lines

Comment: You probably need to reword the question. Although i can see it clearly states "I just need help for the declaration" it looks like everyone has misunderstood you.

Comment: The last part was a recent addition. There are lots of tutorials online that shows C# variable declaration.

Comment: @ranru Yes but it may be different for Unity 3D ?

Comment: If it changes in Unity3d, it is no longer C#. The example you posted is not in the document you linked. Doesn't look like js declaration.

Comment: @ranru I meant the variable declaration isn't the same for Unity 3D for example :
`var Transform object`

Comment: @ranru Yes the one in the document is not JS because I tried to convert it to C# that my best guess lol

Comment: it isn't javascript, the language is called unityscript (I editted the tags to reflect this). It's just similar to js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unityscript declarations, such as your example:

```
var SpawnPoint : Transform;
```

can be written in C# like this:

```
Transform SpawnPoint;
```

another example:

```
var myObject : GameObject;
```

is:

`GameObject myObject;`

You can see the pattern (I hope). Be warned however that there are quite a few other key differences. One such difference that springs to mind is the way [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) and the [WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) method are handled (which are a little more complicated in C#).

Thankfully the documentation on the unity3d site is quite thorough, and has examples in both languages for most of the stuff, so you shouldn't have too much trouble translating your code.